# mysqldumpslow install

Tags: mysql

I would like to install mysqldumpslow on our linux box. we are currently running following versions

show variables like "%version%"
    -> ;

protocol_version         -- 10
version                  -- 5.1.45-community-log
version_comment          -- MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
version_compile_machine  -- x86_64
version_compile_os       -- unknown-linux-gnu

Can someone help me to install mysqldumpslow step-bystep ?

Answer (score 1):

that's hard ... check this first `rpm -qa | grep mysql -i`
if there is match of `MySQL-client-standard`, you probably already have mysqldumpslow installed

if not, run `yum install MySQL-client-standard`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, this is in the package "mysql-client"  The default MySQL server install only includes mysql-client-core, which does not include `mysqldumpslow`.